# Comparing Tool for Reporting Services Objects

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have three Reporting Services Instances (Server), all in version of SQL-Server 2017.

All instances have the same tree structure with hundreds of objects (datasources, datasets and reports)

Now I'm looking for a tool which compares the same objects between two instances. I already use the redgate comparing tools but they do not cover reporting services.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but this is a shopping list question. Take a look at the [`Questions`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%C3%A9race?tab=profile) section in my profile. Take the Tour and visit the Help Centre - you'll get an idea about what's on- and off-topic. p.s. wilkommen auf Forum!

Comment: Thanks, I understand. To which StackExchange forum would my question belong to?

Comment: You could try [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)? p.s. how's my German?

Answer (score 2):

So basically what @saihtam8 said in his comment.

This SO thread might be helpful to you: [Where does a published RDL file sit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914370/where-does-a-published-rdl-file-sit)

Essentially just compare the report BLOB columns (Content? in SQL Server 2008 R2) in the Catalog tables across each server instance. 
In SQL Server 2008 R2, it looks like there are DataSets and DataSource tables as well which you can compare.

Answer (score 1):

Could do a visual studio data compare.  Or download the SSRS objects to a local file (there's a couple of ways to do this via powershell or ssis) and use file compare.

Comment: Is Visual Studio able to do a Compare of remote SSRS objects?
And manually downloading and comparing could work for few objects, but I have hundreds to compare and sync.

Comment: All the ssrs objects are is entries in various tables on the Reportserver Database so if you do a data compare on the data stored in the tables on each of your dbs you should be able to see differences.

Answer (score 0):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is free and will compare the structures and contents of up to 3 folder paths at the same time.

Comment: WinMerge compares files, right?
I want to compare ReportingService-Objects between Servers. These Objects resist in ReportServer-Databases and are not file-based.